# What is the correct way to use the CollectionPage type for a 'category' page?

Tags: schema.org, categories

If I have a category page that has a list of links to the specific items, this page would be a [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage) with [`significantLinks`](http://schema.org/significantLinks), right?

I thought this would be the correct *basic* implementation:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "url": "http://example.com/animals",
  "mainEntity":{
    "@type": "CollectionPage",
    "significantLinks": [
      "http://example.com/animals/dog",
      "http://example.com/animals/cat"
    ]
  }
}
```

But this feels like it's missing something (labels, for example). I also saw the [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) property which seems like it should be used in a page like this, but using both [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) and [`significantLinks`](http://schema.org/significantLinks) feels very disconnected.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage) *instead* of [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage), not in addition to it. `CollectionPage` is a more specific `WebPage`.

---

It seems that [`significantLink`](http://schema.org/significantLink) (for URL values) as well as [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) (for `CreativeWork` values) could be used. But I think `hasPart` is the better choice here, because `significantLink` could also be used for pages that don’t belong to the category (so for consumers it’s not necessarily clear that these are category items), and `hasPart` would allow you to provide metadata (in case you want to display it on the category page).

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "CollectionPage",
  "hasPart": [
    {
      "@type": "ItemPage"
    },
    {
      "@type": "ItemPage"
    },
    {
      "@type": "ItemPage"
    }
  ]
}
```

Another option is to use [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) to reference an [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList). It conveys that the list is the primary entity of the `CollectionPage`, so for consumers it’s probably clear that this is the collection the page is about.

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "CollectionPage",
  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "ItemList",
    "itemListElement": [
      {
        "@type": "ItemPage"
      },
      {
        "@type": "ItemPage"
      },
      {
        "@type": "ItemPage"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: So can/should I use `hasPart` as well as `ItemList`?

Comment: @JohnRPerry: I think it’s not necessary. I would only use `hasPart` if you can’t (or don’t want to) use `mainEntity ItemList`.

Comment: It would be great if you provide html example of `CollectionPage` + `ItemList` of `WebPage` items.

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov: I added two plain examples. If you have a question that goes further than that: you can ask on [so] if the question is about the syntax/rules (not about SEO), you can ask on [webmasters.se] if the question is about the vocabulary/SEO, and you can ask on [codereview.se] if you want a review of your solution.

Comment: @unor Using `hasPart` on a page also should mean to the consumer the same significance/value as using `mainEntity`, is that right? If not, given both possibilities, which one of `hasPart` and `mainEntity` adds more value to the page's schema?

Comment: @EthanCollins: No, they convey different things. First of all, `hasPart` expects a `CreativeWork` value, while `mainEntity` expects any `Thing` (if you have a page about a person, it’s not possible (and doesn’t make sense) to say &lt;`WebPage` `hasPart` `Person`>). But the primary difference is that many things can be part of a creative work, but not all of these things are necessarily the *main*/*primary* things on this page.

Comment: @uor I understand now that matching `@type` is important, missed that. Your last sentence clarifies my initial query - `hasPart` can include any thing, not necessarily the main entity, therefore specificity of `mainEntity` is higher.